# Asymmetric coloring of quads in opengl

Tags: opengl

I need to color some points of a surface consisting of multiple quadrilaterals. The problem is that the color is not symmetric distributed around the point, see image where only the lower right corner of the left square is red while the red color seems to be pulled towards the right upper corner in the right square).

[image]

code:

```
glBegin (GL_QUAD_STRIP);
glVertex3f (1., 0., 0)
glVertex3f (1., 1., 0)
glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
glVertex3f (0., 0., 0)
glColor3f(0, 0, 1)
glVertex3f (0., 1., 0)
glVertex3f (-1., 0., 0)
glVertex3f (-1., 1., 0)
glEnd ();
```

If you make two individual quads and define one clockwise and the other counter clockwise then the color will be symmetric around the point, but different from the color distribution around adjacent points(if they are colored instead).

So how can I color arbitrary points with a symmetric color distribution?

**EDIT:**

I would like to visualize e.g. the temperature of the surface based on the temperature at each vertex, something like the image below (yellow=0, orange=0.5 and red=1):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

By default OpenGL uses a barycentric linear interpolation over each triangle. Which causes exactly what you see. The simplemost solution would be write a set of vertex and fragment shaders that implement a distance based gradient.

The details depend on your specific needs.

Comment: I would like the color to be a linear interpolation of the surrounding four vertices - is that possible.


I have examined several examples and tutorials but none of them accesses position or color of surrounding vertices

Comment: @MadsMPedersen: A linear interpolation, by definition, works only between two vertices. The barycentric interpolation OpenGL does is actually quite close to a simple linear interpolation. I suggest you use a tool like Photoshop and manually draw a picture of what you'd like to see. Post it here and I'll suggest you a method on how to do it in OpenGL.

Comment: @MadsMPedersen: Okay, for an application like *that*, I'd not even bother being clever with vertices and adjacency lists. Your case calls for a texture in GL_NEAREST interpolation mode, which is far simpler to implement and also benefits from the hardwired bilinear interpolators of the GPUs.

Comment: @MadsMPedersen: I think the texture coordinates of your second quad are wrong, hence that asymmetry (please post your drawing code including texture coordinates). Also you should look into "perspective correction", so that things will look correct even if looked at not perpendicular.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33808/discussion-between-mads-m-pedersen-and-datenwolf)

Comment: @MadsMPedersen: You completely misunderstood what I was suggesting. You should not use the texture as a color ramp LUT. I was suggesting to put your grid data into a 2D texture and draw that as one single quad. Use a fragment shader to apply another 1D texture for the color ramp.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I am going to use it for an animation of e.g. temperature distribution on boxes, cylinders and other surfaces, that can be generated as quads between to polygons. So making a new 2d texture in every step might not be convenient. What do you mean by "Use a fragment shader to apply another 1D texture for the color ramp"

Comment: @MadsMPedersen: You don't have to create a new 2D texture. Just update the data with glTexSubImage2D. Normally for things like heat distributions and such, your values are scalars, which, in texture form, are grayscale. To give it color you apply a color ramp. This is done using a fragment shader that takes the color from the scalar field texture and uses it as a lookup coordinate into a 1D texture acting as color ramp.

Comment: Thank you for you help. It is much appreciated. I think I understand how to get the color from the texture grayscale, but not to get the texture grayscale from the four corner scalars. What should my 2D-texture image look like.

Comment: @MadsMPedersen: Technically a texture is a set of sampled interpolation support points. Say you want to display a grid of 5×3, so what you do is create a texture of dimensions 5×3 and give each "pixel" the sampling value. Then by mapping that whole texture on a single, large quad, the OpenGL rasterizer will do all the bilinear interpolation for you.

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of help from datenwolf I ended up with the following way to go:

- Make 8bit 2D texture of node scalars (e.g. temperature)
- in fragment shader look up greyscale level in 1D colormap texture

And the code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import sys
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import shaders

def LoadTexture():
    global ID
    arr = np.array([[0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.int8)
    im = Image.fromarray(arr, "L")
    ix, iy, image = im.size[0], im.size[1], im.tobytes()
    ID = glGenTextures(1)

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, ix, iy, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

def loadColorMap(imageName="jet.bmp"):
    im = Image.open(imageName)
    ix, _, image = im.size[0], im.size[1], im.tostring("raw", "RGBX", 0, -1)
    ID = glGenTextures(1)
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, ID);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, 3, ix, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)  # avoids 1 => 0
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D)
    return ID



glutInit(sys.argv)
glutCreateWindow("")


VERTEX_SHADER = shaders.compileShader("""
void main() {
        gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
        gl_Position = ftransform();
}""", GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

FRAGMENT_SHADER = shaders.compileShader("""

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler1D colormap;
void main() {
    float level = texture2D(texture, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].s, gl_TexCoord[0].t)).r;
    gl_FragColor = texture1D(colormap, level);
}""", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

LoadTexture()
loadColorMap()

shader = shaders.compileProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER)


shaders.glUseProgram(shader)
texloc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, 'texture');
glUniform1i(texloc, 0);
texloc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "colormap");
glUniform1i(texloc, 1);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(45.0, 1, 0.1, 100.0)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()  # Reset The View
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.0)  # Move Into The Screen

glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP)
glTexCoord2f(1. / 6, .25); glVertex3f(-1, 0, 0)
glTexCoord2f(1. / 6, .75); glVertex3f(-1, 1, 0)
glTexCoord2f(.5, .25);glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
glTexCoord2f(.5, .75);glVertex3f(0, 1, 0)
glTexCoord2f(5. / 6, .25);glVertex3f(1, 0, 0)
glTexCoord2f(5. / 6, .75); glVertex3f(1, 1, 0)
glEnd()

glutSwapBuffers()

glutMainLoop()
```

that produces this image:

[image]